# How to store rand() value in a session variable without overwriting it on the next execution

Tags: php

I am writing some demo webapps for a client and I need a article generator that will use session variable `_article_id` as a stored integer value to choose "most important" article of the day from MySQL database.

I'm running `rand(1,99)` inside `$_SESSION['_article_id']` but the value seems to be changing because It's executing the function over and over again on every new request.

How do I store rand() output to a variable so it stays unchanged during the session?

Thanks.

Comment: show what you have now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe check if this variable isset?

```php
if(!isset($_SESSION['_article_id'])){
   $_SESSION['_article_id'] = rand(1,99);
}
```

https://www.php.net/isset

Comment: I'm in a hurry so something like this would never have gone through my mind. Thank you :)

I'll accept the answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

```
function generatePIN($digits = 4)
    {
        $i = 0; //counter
        $pin = ""; //our default pin is blank.
        while($i < $digits){
            //generate a random number between 0 and 9.
            $pin .= mt_rand(0, 9);
            $i++;
        }
        return $pin;
    }
if (!isset($_SESSION['_article_id'])){
$_SESSION['_article_id'] = generatePIN();
}
```